# How to retrieve VSTS Build variables?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to get the values for custom variables being used in the build? I know they can be dumped to the console output as per what this example describe. But still want to find an easier way to archive it.

http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2017/08/04/dump-all-environment-variables-during-a-tfs-vsts-build/

Comment: What's the easier way that you want? What you want to do after getting the value? How about check the `Settable at queue time` option of build variable and check values when queue build?

Comment: When you say "archive it" how do you plan to use that value? Do you need to retrieve that value with API to do some diagnostic?

Comment: Simply need to allow others to review what parameters being used in an execution and also to reuse them in the next execution. Have been spoiled by the 'Rebuild Last' plugin in Jenkins and seeking for a similar thing on vsts.

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the easier way then the way you provided to retrieve build variables, the value of variable can be changed during the build time ([Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)), so it’s better to retrieve the variable at the end of the build (the way you provided).

Note, the secret variables can’t be output as general text.